# Uk Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa arrival dates

Tags: visas, schengen

My partner and I are planning to travel to the UK/ EU in May 2015. As my partner is a dual passport holder (Australian and British) I am hoping to apply for an Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa that will allow me to work legally in the UK while we are spending our 90 days off from the Schengen area.

We were planning to make the Netherlands our first stop but my question is that as I will be applying for the UK working visa to start in May 2015 for the duration of 2 years, will I need to fly into the UK from Australia or am I able to fly into the Netherlands and arrive in the UK 90 days later without any problems?

Comment: Fairly sure the UK doesn't care from where you arrive, but I'll leave it for someone with an official source to answer.

Comment: Especially since it's almost impossible to fly 'direct' into the UK from Australia - as a Kiwi, when I did it I stopped in Dubai for a few days enroute as well.

Comment: Hi Mark Mayo thanks for the response what I should have said was am I able to travel throughout the EU or am I required to  fly to the uk with a stopover included before commencing my travelling =)

Comment: great, but please edit that into your question - others may easily miss the comments.

Comment: Hi Gayot Fow thanks for the response I we let the carrier I decide to go with know my circumstances before commencing travel later this year.

Answer (score 3):

You are Australian.  You plan to apply for a T5 and if successful, you will present your entry clearance on a flight arriving from the EU rather than Australia and want to know if it's ok.

From a legal point of view, it's fine.  From an operational point of view, you should plan for some delay (but not detention) when clearing UK immigration. The reason for this is that they may not be expecting a T5 arrival from a flight originating in the Netherlands and may not have duty IO's up-to-speed on how to conduct a PBS landing interview (i.e., not your fault).

The landing interview is likely to focus on if there has been a change of circumstances prompting your arrival from a 3rd country. Given that this can be suitably explained, you would expect a standard PBS arrival interview and nothing more.

You can also inform the carrier that you are non-EU and arriving as a T5.  They can notify the immigration desk.  All in all, it is not a big deal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Out of interest, what is PBS? Post...Border Security?

Comment: PBS = Points Based System. Economic migrants. They get asked a different set of questions.